# Change TTY as soon as it is shown

Tags: command-line, 16.04, tty

I am running a fully console based Linux (Ubuntu Mini 16.04 LTS). Therefore I will only ever make use of `tty1` to `tty6`. However when I boot it starts in `tty7`, which is the graphical part (which I don't have installed). Seeing this:

[image] each time I start my system is quite annoying. How can I make it switch to `tty1` by default?

I've tried adding `chvt 1` into `/etc/rc.local` but no luck. Any help?

Comment: https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1830359